# How to filter data within certain threshold in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, filter, signals, outliers, threshold

To remove data above 1.2 and below -1.2.

I use the following function:

```
threshold = [-1.2, 1.2];
y = rmoutliers(y,'percentiles',threshold);
```

But error occurred:

*Error using isoutlier>parseinput (line 236)
'Percentiles' value must be a sorted 2-element numeric vector with entries between 0 and 100.*

Any other functions which can be used to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Removing them is straight forward.  Assuming you need to remove the points from both the x and y axis data then,

```
idx_to_remove = ((y<-1.2)|(y>1.2));
x(idx_to_remove) = [];
y(idx_to_remove) = [];
```

But do you need to remove them or saturate them to the appropriate limit instead?  For saturation `x` wouldn't change, but you'd do the following to `y`,

```
y(y < -1.2) = -1.2;
y(y > 1.2) = 1.2;
```

Comment: I think that `y = min(max(y,-1.2),1.2)` is faster than using indexing, but I haven't timed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to leave the `x` axis variable unchanged (i.e. the number of elements should stay the same), it would be a good idea to convert the outliers to `NaN`.

```
y( abs(y)>1.2 ) = NaN;
```

If you want to remove the elements, you can use `[]` instead of `NaN`.

```
y( abs(y)>1.2 ) = [];
```

This condition `abs(y)>1.2` tests for an absolute (positive) value greater than `1.2`, if your thresholds were different then you could test them separately

```
y( y > 1.2 | y < -1.2 ) = NaN;
```